# How to block internet access for wine applications?

Tags: wine, security, firewall

How can one prevent specific or any wine applications from accessing the internet?

When using certain applications under Windows, they were trying to access the internet from time to time without any obvious reason. I was able to prevent that behaviour with a personal firewall back then. Unfortunately I did not find an application level firewall in Ubuntu up to now. This is especially annoying when I am abroad using data-roaming with my 3G modem.

Comment: You can try my noinet preload.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/249826/how-to-disable-internet-connection-for-a-single-process/393013#393013

Comment: Can smb. extend the answers / provide an additional answer that works with nftables?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There's a nice tutorial on blocking any given program from accessing the Internet on the [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1188099).

**Steps**

```
sudo addgroup no-internet  # Create group "no-internet"
sudo adduser $USER no-internet  # Add current user to no-internet
```

iptables rule to prevent that group from accessing the network

```
sudo iptables -I OUTPUT 1 -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -j DROP
sudo ip6tables -I OUTPUT 1 -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -j DROP # To also block IPv6 traffic
```

Process you don't want to have internet access using `sg` [or `sudo -g`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25300192/4970442) (execute command as different group ID):

```
sg no-internet -c "processFullPath args"
```

It basically involves creating a new group, denying it Internet access, and then running any program you want to restrict as that group ID. So in your case, you would just always run wine using the method described in the tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, that's it! But I don't understand, why someone has voted you down. Your answer is exactly what I had hoped for.

Comment: It's a great answer if you follow the link, but I suspect the DV was because it is a mostly link answer.  If you want the how, you have to go to the forums.  That said, it got an upvote from me.

Comment: To elaborate: to run a command under the new group use: `sg no-internet -c "command args"`. Also note: apparently this iptable rule does not drop pings, so if you gonna test whether it's working, use netcat instead. **EDIT**: I also noted: it doesn't drop IPv6 connections, so you only have blocked UDP and TCP of IPv4.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Probably should be the same args but with `ip6tables`.

Comment: This could be further revised to indicate how to always make this match that no-internet group without having to execute `sg no-internet -c ...` - force the user's default group who you want to block to `no-internet` - `sudo usermod -g no-internet USERNAME` will force `no-internet` as the user's default group, and then always match the rule without having to specify the group to execute something as.

Answer (score 17):

Make a group and become a member of it

```
addgroup wino

adduser $USER wino
```

Now enter an `iptables` rule to block that group from using the internet 
you can type this on the terminal and hit enter

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner wino -j REJECT
```

To make this rule run after each reboot with systemd use `iptables-persistent save` from `iptables-persistent` package.

If [using rc-local](https://askubuntu.com/a/840839/349837): You can put the rule in `/etc/rc.local`. Make sure the last line in that text file says `exit 0`.

Usage example:

```
sg wino "wine executablename.exe"
```

You need the `" "` and also type wine before the programs name.

Comment: I've edited your `usermod` command to add `-a`. Without `-a`, you will end up removing the user from all other supplementary groups (like `admin`, `cdrom`, etc.)! It is also more convenient to use `addgroup`/`adduser`.

Comment: was just about to fix the -a myself. yes do not start wine as root !. only need root to make the iptables rule.  the usage example was for normal user after doing those steps.

Comment: ah sorry, my mistake. removed comment.

Comment: @gertvdijk I edited the commands once more, `adduser <username> <groupname>` is the sensible thing here.

Comment: is there any possibility to make it default that internet is blocked for that program (i.e. making the `sg` call obsolete, e.g. by `chown`ing the program) ?

Comment: I need to run it using `cgexec` to also limit memory usage, any idea how to use it instead of `sg` ? just to test it, as it seems a system (and not wine specific), I ran `sg wino google-chrome` or with `links2` and both were able to connect, but `ping` failed! could someone explain that (specific question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397834/why-does-firewall-blocking-an-application-by-group-may-not-work))?

Answer (score 11):

EDIT few years later for software not fan of proxy settings & overall a much cleaner & simpler answer :

use bublewrap + unshare to launch your app :

```
bwrap --unshare-net wine yourapp.exe
```

---

changing proxies / original answer

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"MigrateProxy"=dword:00000001
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000001
"ProxyHttp.1.1"=dword:00000000
"ProxyOverride"="<local>"
"ProxyServer"="http://NonExistantProxyAddress:80"
"User Agent"="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1"
```

to add to your wine (or playonlinux virtual drives) registry :

much simpler solution indeed than using groups (& does not prevent pol to connect, just the apps)

credits to http://ootput.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/block-wine-applications-from-the-internet/comment-page-1/

Comment: this only blocks access for software which honors proxy settings, most dont obviously... so this is not a valid solution!

Comment: like which one ? (all software i've been using with pol were blocked indeed). hence i'm not convinced by your statement : it is valid in many cases, might not be in some, but which one ?

Comment: no its not. eg; any software that just connects to a host:port via TCP will continue to function. A HTTP proxy setting is something a program has to recognize and honor. If you dont believe me, get/compile software which connects to another host via TCP and see it for yourself.

Comment: @K1773R finally had to work around this, updated my desktop shortcut to `bwrap --unshare-net wine mywindowsapp.exe`

Answer (score 8):

Simply run app as:

```
systemd-run --scope -p IPAddressDeny=any wine myapp.exe
```

[The `IPAddressDeny=…` allows to deny access](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html#) to a set of IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. Special value `any` disables access to all of them for all IP-based protocols, like TCP, UDP, ICMP, SCTP, etc.

Example of usage *(note: for this demo I had to fix `wine ping`, since it was timing out on me)*:

```bsh
$ export WINEDEBUG=-all   # remove debug prints for the demo
$ wine ping localhost     # check that ping works
Pinging localhost [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1
        Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
        Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms
$ systemd-run --scope -p IPAddressDeny=any wine ping localhost   # well, not anymore
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ====
Authentication is required to manage system services or other units.
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 1.  constantine
 2.  archie
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2): 1
Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ====
Running scope as unit: run-u28936.scope
Pinging localhost [127.0.0.1] with 32 bytes of data:
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
PING: transmit failed. General failure.

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1
        Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)
```

For the rest of the answer I gonna copy text from [my other similar answer on unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/536046/59928):

---

Note: this gonna ask you for a password but the app gets launched as your user. Do not allow this to delude you into thinking that the command needs `sudo`, because that would cause the command to run under root, which hardly was your intention.

If you want to not enter the password *(after all, you already own your resources, why would you need a password to limit them)*, you could use `--user` option, however for this to work you gonna need cgroupsv2 support enabled, which right now [requires to boot with `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy` kernel parameter](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/13347#issuecomment-522477870).

Comment: This is the proper answer or any system that uses systemd.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the cleanest solution, but as a temporary solution for [PlayOnLinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayOnLinux) users, it is easy and fast to setup.

Go to Settings > Internet

Enable `Set a proxy` and enter a website without a proxy e.g. `stackoverflow.com` and random user name and password. The programs won't reach the proxy server or the internet.

**Warning:** Be aware, that this will also prevent the install dialog from searching and installing new software!

[image: s]

Comment: Same caveat as [mikakun's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/473143/495331). No good.

Comment: @Marc.2377 I know

Comment: @Alwin07 launch with bwrap : `bwrap --unshare-net wine mywindowsapp.exe`