# How to control internet access for each program?

Tags: firewall, iptables

I would like to use a software to control which program may connect to the internet. I know that this behaviour is associated with the word "firewall", but some Linux users are very upset if somebody demands a Personal Firewall. I don't want to upset you by demand such a program.
I don't want to "secure ports" or other stuff a Personal Firewall promises on Windows. I looked into `iptables` but it does not fit my requirements.

I saw an excellent answer here (["How to block internet access for wine applications"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19346/how-to-block-internet-access-for-wine-applications)) but it's very uncomfortable to set this up.

Is there a software that asks for each program if it may access the internet?

Comment: on mac there is a software called **little snitch** that does this. I think there is a windows version also...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [Perl script](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Skripte/anfd) in the German Ubuntu forum ([Google-translated to English](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&ie=UTF8&nv=1&prev=_m&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Skripte/anfd)) that seems to do that. I never tried it and I didn't take a closer look at the script, but maybe it works for you. The description is in German only so you may need a translation service (like Google Translate; see above).

Comment: I will have a look at it. It's interesting an may be the right tool. Unfortunately, there's no gui, but it shouldn't stop me :)

Answer (score 40):

I [found](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1188099&s=73e8a8809da60f5e49641129388c7658) a convenient solution that solves the problem. You create a group that is never allowed to use the internet and start the program as a member of this group.

1. Create a group `no-internet`. Do **not** join this group

   ```
   sudo addgroup no-internet
   ```
2. Add a rule to iptables that prevents all processes belonging to the group `no-internet` from using the network (use `ip6tables` to also prevent IPv6 traffic)

   ```
   sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -j DROP
   ```
3. Execute [`sudo -g no-internet YOURCOMMAND`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25300192/4970442) instead of `YOURCOMMAND`.

You can easily write a wrapper script that uses sudo for you. You can get rid of the password prompt by adding

```
%sudo     ALL=(:no-internet)      NOPASSWD: ALL
```

or, something similar with `sudo visudo`

Use the `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` to persist firewall rules.

Comment: I tried your guide, `sudo -g no-internet firefox` connects faster than default one. It doesn't work.

Comment: @kenn I can only say that it works fine here. I would guess that you are doing something wrong when creating the rule. Not saving the rule, not making the script executable or something like that.

Comment: I rebooted and applied above rules again with no luck

Comment: It was `sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -j DROP` for me, `sudo` was required.

Comment: worked perfectly for me, even with firefox. thank you!

Comment: This is great. I hate solutions where you have to install additional software etc.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me either, on Ubuntu 19.04. I did have to install iptables-persistent in order to allow the changes to be saved between reboots. (So you might want to add that to the solution above). However, sudo -g no-internet firefox does not restrict Firefox from accessing internet. Conceptually, this solution seems like it should work. Is there something fundamental that is being overlooked? For example do we need to setup BOTH ipv4 and ipv6 to make this work?

Comment: Better option is to change gid to root in your iptable rule then setup a second allow rule which one can then sudo as for allowing access or applying that group to the process's file if needed regularly.

think of it defaulting to a blacklist and whitelisting allowed processes instead of an opt-in blacklist.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for nftables?

Comment: According to `iptables-translate`, the NFTables equivalent is: `nft add rule ip filter OUTPUT skgid "$(getent group no-internet|cut -f3 -d:)" counter drop`

Comment: Nowadays, you probably also need to do it for IPv6 using a command like `sudo ip6tables -A OUTPUT -m owner --gid-owner no-internet -j DROP` and make it persistent using `sudo service netfilter-persistent save` (after installing the netfilter-persistent package).

Comment: Hi! If I want allow ONLY the group has-internet I do: `sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner !--gid-owner has-internet -j DROP` , when I do `sudo -g has-internet YOURCOMMAND` (i.e. `sudo -g has-internet ping somerandomsite.com` cannot connect... Why? Should I join or not the has-internet group? Should I use the option --suppl-groups  in the rule? Thanks!!!!!

Comment: PS I've created a new question: https://askubuntu.com/posts/1458243/edit

Answer (score 38):

> NOTE: Douane is no longer actively developed and is reported to not work in later Ubuntu versions.  This solution may not work, but the answer is kept as is for historical reasons.

In case you're still looking for this kind of application, I am currently developing exactly that application: http://douaneapp.com/ https://gitlab.com/douaneapp/Douane

My application blocks any unknown applications (new versions of an authorized application are blocked) and asks you if you Allow or Deny its traffic.

Have a look at the website ;-)

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Cool! I looked also at ppa but no package there despite application is created there. 
Also I wonder if it could show the ip resolved to a readable site name? 
And, I am going to follow the compilation instructions, I saw many tips for ubuntu dep packages there, and I will use checkinstall to create my local copy of .deb packages to easily manage upgrades (remove/install). 
May be checkinstall could be used to create your distributables too I think.

Comment: You can open feature request on Github (https://github.com/Douane/Douane/issues) :)

Comment: uh, it seems exactly what I needed!! But I can't find a package to install it on Ubuntu.

Comment: Still not package for Ubuntu?

Comment: Nope, no none came to me regarding Ubuntu :(

Comment: @ZedTuX can you make a Ubuntu package?

Comment: Sorry @MarkYisri I'm not a packager but I'll be more than happy to help someone in packaging Douane in any kind of package managers.

Comment: @ZedTuX give me a bit to stab this, if it's not too complicated to convert into a buildable package, I'll run some test compiles automatically on a PPA; from there if all works to your satisfaction, then you can start pointing right at that PPA.  (I have several workflows for different programs, so developing an automated workflow wouldn't be a problem heh).

Comment: @ThomasWard hey nice to read! Feel free to open an issue on Github so that I can better follow your progresses.

Comment: @ZedTuX I'm *far* from ready packages, I've got a lot of things to deal with after all heh.

Comment: @ZedTuX is Douane abandoned? Site return 5xx http status, on Gitlab everything (like installation docs) points to non-existan urls on github. BTW if deb is too much cumbersome consider packaging to appimage/flatpack/snap.

Comment: Hello @PabloBianchi. Sorry about those issues. I have migrated to Gitlab in a quite quick and dirty way. Also I have all my websites down 'cause I need to some time to fix them all, but Douane is not abounded, it's just that I don't have enough time (baby stuff to do ;)) but if anyone is opening PR or issues, I'm available! Thank you for your comment and for your interest in Douane !! ;-)

Comment: I fixed the broken links in the README.md file.

Comment: Douaneapp.com is back ! :)

Comment: Nonetheless I have to update a link on the website in order to point to Gitlab.

Comment: The new website is online with all links fixed, a new "Roadmap" section and also I'm featuring the shiny new installer which automate the Douane installation with a single click (on the "Next" button ;))

Comment: @ZedTuX About the freeze bug, is it solved? I'm planning to install it on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Hey @darksoulsong, I'm still working on it, but with a very little amount of time, unfortunately. Join us on https://gitter.im/Douane/General?utm_source=share-link&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=share-link in order to get the most up-to-date info!

Answer (score 16):

Another option is **[firejail](https://firejail.wordpress.com/documentation-2/basic-usage/)**. It runs the application inside sandbox where you control if the application could see the network:

```
firejail --net=none firefox
```

This command will start Firefox browser without internet access.
Note that the firejail distribution in the Ubuntu repo is *outdated* - better download its latest LTS version from the firejail home page.

Comment: Very lightweight and very useful. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 6):

Running a program under another user will use the config files for that user and not yours.

Here is a solution that does not require modifying the firewall rules, and runs under the same user (via `sudo`) with a modified environment, where your user is `my_user` and the app you want to run is `my_app`:

```
# run app without access to internet
sudo unshare -n sudo -u my_user my_app
```

For more details see [`man unshare`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unshare.2.html) and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83348/209677).

### Linux GUI firewall

If you are looking for a GUI firewall I've had good results with [OpenSnitch](https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch) — it's not yet in ubuntu repos and I wouldn't call it production-level, but following the build steps from the [github](https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch/blob/master/README.md) page worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

There is already a firewall in Ubuntu, [`ufw`](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/firewall.html), but it is disabled by default. You can enable and use it by the command line or its frontend, [**gufw**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/gufw/), that is installable directly from the Ubuntu Software Centre.

If you need to block the internet access to a specific application, you can try [LeopardFlower](http://sourceforge.net/projects/leopardflower/), which is still in beta version and it is not available in the Ubuntu Software Centre:

Answer (score 3):

@psusi:
I really wish people wouldn't peddle bad and not useful information. IPTables allows one to do this, so I'd hardly consider it "foolhardy". 
Just saying "NO" without understanding a use case is somewhat narrow minded. 
http://www.debian-administration.org/article/120/Application_level_firewalling

EDIT bodhi.zazen

NOTE - THIS OPTION WAS REMOVED FROM IPTABLES IN 2005, 8 YEARS BEFORE THIS ANSWER WAS POSTED

SEE - http://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter/msg49716.html

> commit 34b4a4a624bafe089107966a6c56d2a1aca026d4 Author: Christoph
>   Hellwig  **Date:   Sun Aug 14 17:33:59 2005 -0700**
>
> [NETFILTER]: Remove tasklist_lock abuse in ipt{,6}owner
>
> **Rip out cmd/sid/pid matching since its unfixable broken**  and stands in the
>       way of locking changes to tasklist_lock.
>
> ```
> Signed-off-by: Christoph Hellwig <hch@xxxxxx>
> Signed-off-by: Patrick McHardy <kaber@xxxxxxxxx>
> Signed-off-by: David S. Miller <davem@xxxxxxxxxxxxx>
> ```

Comment: To anyone considering flagging this: This should not be a comment instead, it *answers the question that was asked*. @user141987 I do recommend expanding this to provide more information about how to set up `iptables` to implement per-application restrictions, however. I recommend including the important information in your answer (and still providing the link, for reference).

Comment: iptables does NOT filter by application.

Comment: That article appears to be misinformation since there is no such option.  The reason why requests to create such an option in the past were rejected is because it would be inherently unreliable; an application can simply change its name.

Comment: @psusi Are you saying "If your kernel was compiled with CONFIG_IP_NF_MATCH_OWNER then you can configure your iptables firewall to allow or reject packets on a per-command basis" is incorrect? Or simply that most kernels don't include the option? If this is incorrect, are there sources of information that debunk it? (Also, please note that the primary purpose of per-application firewall restrictions is not to try to make it perfectly safe to run untrusted applications. The purpose is primarily to give the user a measure of control beyond applications' built-in configuration options.)

Comment: This option was removed from the kernel in 2005, 8 years before this answer was given - http://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter/msg49716.html and despite claims to the contrary is inaccurate, you can NOT application filter with iptables.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the solution posted [here](https://plus.google.com/+TobyKurien/posts/YZhZJCZmGgm) to be a good one.  It involves creating a user-group for which internet access is *allowed*, and setting up firewall rules to allow access only for this group.  The only way for an application to access the internet is if it is run by a member of this group.  You can run programs under this group by opening a shell with `sudo -g internet -s`.

To recap what's in the post I linked above:

1. Create the "internet" group by typing the following into a shell: `sudo groupadd internet`
2. Ensure that the user who will run the script below is added to the `sudo` group in `/etc/group`.  If you end up modifying this file, then you will need to log out and back in before the script below will work.
3. Create a script containing the following, and run it:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   # Firewall apps - only allow apps run from "internet" group to run

   # clear previous rules
   sudo iptables -F

   # accept packets for internet group
   sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m owner --gid-owner internet -j ACCEPT

   # also allow local connections
   sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
   sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 192.168.0.1/24 -j ACCEPT

   # reject packets for other users
   sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -j REJECT

   # open a shell with internet access
   sudo -g internet -s
   ```
4. By running the above script, you will have a shell in which you can run applications with internet access.

Note that this script doesn't do anything to save and restore your firewall rules.  You may wish to modify the script to use the `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` shell commands.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Leopard Flower](https://github.com/themighty1/lpfw). It has a GUI and per-application restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

For better or worse, Linux uses a different approach. There is no simple graphical interface to offer this functionality. There are many discussions on this topic on the internet and you can find interesting discussions if you google search. While debate is interesting, to date there has not been a dedicated group of programmers wanting to write and maintain this functionality.

The tools that offer this functionality in Linux are Apparmor, Selinux, and Tomoyo.

None of these tools are overly easy to learn and all have advantages and disadvantages. Personally I prefer SELinux, although SELinux has a steeper learning curve.

See:

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/12/06/3-application-level-firewalls-for-linux-distributions/

There was (is) an application that has been referenced already, leopardflower. I am not sure of the status / maintance.

Answer (score 1):

It was in iptables up to kernel version 2.6.24
If you are running a 2.x - 2.6.24 machine and your kernel has it complied in you can do it. 
for some reason they took it out, so no its not microsoft. 
http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/IP_NF_MATCH_OWNER.html

Comment: http://www.debian-administration.org/?article=120

Answer (score -1):

No, it isn't possible.  It also isn't part of the traditional definition of a firewall.  It is something that Microsoft came up with fairly recently in an attempt to paper around their fundamentally broken OS security problems.  It is considered foolhardy and unworkable in the Linux community because one program that isn't allowed can simply run another program that is and gain access that way.

If you don't like what a program is doing on the network when you run it, then don't run that program.

Comment: Microsoft's firewall was *not* the first major firewall to offer this functionality. It wasn't even the first *Windows* firewall to offer it. BlackIce Defender, ZoneAlarm, and a variety of other software firewalls for Windows predate the introduction of the Windows Internet Connection Firewall by years. Furthermore, *there is no such consensus in the Linux community.* We often use AppArmor (or SELinux) to constrain the behavior of applications (and I wonder if AppArmor could be adapted to this purpose...). There's no reason it's "wrong" to want to control what apps can access the Internet.

Comment: And, as several other answers can attest, per-application firewall restrictions are *quite possible*; this functionality is built into iptables/netfilter!

Comment: No, neither netfilter nor iptables can filter per application. They can filter by user and port but not per application.

Comment: "Can simply run another"???? Then obviously the creator of such a program that doesn't block the child processes of the target program is vastly flawed.