# Is there an application firewall for Linux, like ZoneAlarm

Tags: firewall, iptables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to control internet access for each program?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45072/how-to-control-internet-access-for-each-program)

I've tried Firestarter and Ufw, but in the end, decided to write my own iptables scripts. I basically let http and https, 53, and if needed, the port for PPA key adding. (If people want to chat online when using this machine, they can sign into their webmails or facebook).

I was wondering though, is there a firewall that will allow me to block all applications from accessing the internet, and then let me whitelist the applications that I want to allow access to the internet? (This kind of like the ZoneAlarm firewall for Windows).

Ive heard about using the users and groups to block all people accessing the internet, and then assigning certain applications that can be used, but this seems very makeshift.

There's an Android app called Droidwall that apparently uses iptables to blacklist all apps from accessing the internet, and then allows you to whitelist the ones you want.

Any ideas, or perhaps iptables script examples?