# Alternative to Little-Snitch app-firewall?

Tags: software-recommendation, firewall

I'm trying out Ubuntu. Been a Mac user. I like ubuntu a lot but I'm uncomfortable not having an app-firewall that reports what connections are being made to the internet. I find it unnerving to not have any control over what can & cannot connect to the internet.

Little Snitch works great on the Mac for this purpose. Is there anything comparable on Ubuntu? The default UFW firewall cannot stop apps from connecting so is pretty useless.

Comment: ufw can stop apps from connecting.  you should revise your question

Comment: no it can't. ufw can only block ports and IPs.

Comment: permit port X deny any stops all apps.  if what you want is dropping a specific app's traffic, you do that with ld_preload

Comment: how do I permit firefox traffic over port 80 but prevent Dash from connecting to port 80?

Comment: ld_preload - you should add that to your question

Comment: I will create a new question, will you please answer it, thanks aking1012. http://askubuntu.com/questions/135148/how-do-i-use-ld-preload-to-control-what-apps-can-and-cannot-connect-to-interne

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to control internet access for each program?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/45072/how-to-control-internet-access-for-each-program)

Comment: AppArmor policies can limit capabilities of an application, so in this way one can prevent them access internet.

Comment: Please only recommend one solution per answer so that we can vote on them separately. It is possible to post multiple answers.

Comment: Etherape is very detailed to show you every single connection and where it's connecting to but it's not a firewall.

Answer (score 8):

Linux application firewalls have not yet caught on and there have been various third party projects that come and go over the years.

Currently the best, IMO, is [Leopard Flower](http://sourceforge.net/projects/leopardflower/)

[image]

There are detailed instructions on how to install Leopard Flower [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/leopardflower/files/)

Note: It was written for Ubuntu 10.10

Install dependencies (python-qt4 is for the graphical front end)

```
sudo apt-get install iptables libnetfilter-queue libnetfilter-conntrack python-qt4
```

Download the zip file from http://sourceforge.net/projects/leopardflower/files/latest/download

Extract the zip file

This will extract a directory, `lpfw`

Open a terminal and cd into the directory (Assuming it is in ~/Downloads)

```
cd ~/Downloads/lpfw
```

Run the program

```
sudo ./lpfw
```

See the above link for more detailed instructions as well as more advanced configuration.

Comment: it's not available in the repos? I have to go outside to get it? I have a practice of only installing from repos, so I'd prefer not to go outside. But I'm going to check this out.

Comment: No, it is not in the repos, sorry.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen : instructions severely outdated, package must be built from source now.

Comment: @izx - OUCH !!! That is sort of the problem with application firewalls in Linux, a project pops up, but seems to fall unmaintained. Does it build from source ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen: yes -- on precise, but with deps, etc. it's not a DIY for newbies. Dep names have changed, etc. Someone needs to make a deb package/PPA out of it.

Comment: What does +150 mean for this answer? I hope 150 was not awarded. This is nice answer but it is not usable/installable and not even available in repos. Plus very out of date and not supported.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Compile from source works on 13.04, instructions are in the README & INSTALL file. Does exactly what the OP wanted.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen also, program author is working on a rewrite to address seperation of concerns, I suggested on his github repo that dbus be considered to help with the separation. At the moment without the GUI running, new rules can't be created, and there is no feedback about why packets are dropped. I mean, if you create rules to block firefox from going to some website, then in six months will you remember why said website isn't loading?

Comment: Is there a activly maintained alternative to Leopard Flower? `As of 2014-01-12, this project is no longer under active development.`

Comment: @VictorHäggqvist No, all these applications seem to die the same death.

Comment: https://github.com/themighty1/lpfw seems to be the new home

Comment: The project seems to mave moved to GitHub, and it the README now says: "UPDATE October 2020. I no longer plan to contribute to this project because a better alternative with an active maintainer and community has appeared over the last years. I recommend using OpenSnitch ( https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch ) which uses similar techniques to LPFW."

Comment: Please downvote this out-of-date answer, (or if you're the author, please delete it).

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a fresh application (GTK 3), have a look to my application (in heavy development) at http://douaneapp.com/

Comment: Has anyone tried this?  I'd be interested in feedback, it's a very nice looking application.  Any update on the process of getting listed in the Ubuntu Software Center? (per http://askubuntu.com/q/357002/31592 )

Comment: The application is not yet stable and will never been in the USC as they rejected my app (due to the fact that it has a kernel module ......)

Comment: Ah, alright.  Well, hopefully it's stable soon.  There must be some process or steps that USC recommends for applications that depend on kernel modules, right?

Comment: Well they just said to me that it's not secure. The guy hasn't gave me any tips on how to make it possible...

Comment: that stinks.  Any update at this point?  I feel like this app is something a lot of folks would like to use with Ubuntu, however I'd want the backing of the Ubuntu Software Center first.

Comment: have you seen this abandoned project? http://sourceforge.net/projects/leopardflower/files/Source/, that one does not seem to use kernel modules; I wonder if some tips could be found there may be? despite I think the way firewall works have changed so much that we cant even compile it anymore and your project may be the only way now!

Comment: Well Douane has been built on the Linux Kernel Netfilter hooks. Changing this would mean rewriting the entire project. :)

Comment: BTW if there are people how want to contribute, I will be more than happy to collaborate!

Comment: @ZedTuX just tested it now, awesome work. Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Mena! You can also thanks the contributors ;-)

Comment: FYI I'm currently working on the project again (as much as I can). I made a new website (https://douaneapp.com) and also an installer (look at the website). On the website I've made a "Roadmap" section where you can see what I'm working on. If anyone wants to help me, you're all very welcome!

Answer (score 6):

Some GUI suggestions that maybe fit your needs.

[Program Guard](http://pgrd.sourceforge.net/) allows users of a Linux workstation to control which programs access the Internet, last updated, 2006

[image: Progran Guard]

[Gufw](http://gufw.tuxfamily.org/) an interface powered by ufw, last updated, 2012

[image: Gufw]

[FireFlier](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fireflier/) last updated, 2009

[image: FireFlier]

[Guarddog](http://www.simonzone.com/software/guarddog/) last updated, 2007.

[image]

[TuxGuardian](http://tuxguardian.sourceforge.net/) last updated, 2006.

[image]

[InJoy Firewall™](http://www.fx.dk/download/) commercial application (offers a 30 day trial version) last updated, 2007.

[image]

Comment: TuxGuardian looks like it provides what I'm looking for; however, it's no longer supported and badly out of date :( (upticked for TuxGuardian suggestion)

Comment: @Chad--24216 I see, however check out Program Guard also --added recently to my answer

Comment: Please only recommend one solution per answer post, that way, we can vote on each app separately.

Answer (score 3):

**anfd** is a perl script which does the job, but it is not at all as userfriendly as little snitch. There is a good, but German [wiki page](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Skripte/anfd). Download the script [here](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/_attachment?target=Skripte/anfd/anfd) and run it with `anfd -h` to see the following help text:

```
anfd - Ain't no firewall daemon.

anfd [-D] [-i 'iptables command'] [-x] [-c configfile] [-p pidfile]
anfd -k [-p pidfile]
anfd (-h|-?)

Anfd is a userspace daemon that uses the netfilter-ip_queue mechanism to hinder
specific software from "phoning home". It is not security software but privacy
software.

Options:
        -h, -?      : Print this help message.
        -D          : Debug mode - don't detach from terminal and print detailed infos
        -i 'command': Use this iptables command to insert the QUEUE rule.
                      Default: $ipt
        -x          : Dont insert any iptables rule. Admin will take care of that
                      herself.
        -c file     : Use this config file. Default: $default_config
        -p pidfile  : Use this pid file. Default: $pid_file
        -k          : Kill running anfd process.
```

Answer (score 3):

## OpenSnitch

[OpenSnitch](https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch) is application firewall inspired by Little Snitch that works on Ubuntu. Here's a screenshot of a prompt OpenSnitch displays when Firefox tries to connect to the Internet:

[image: Screenshot]

## Installation instructions on Ubuntu 23.04 or later:

Run this command:

```
sudo apt install opensnitch
```

Now launch "OpenSnitch" from your GUI.

## Installation instructions for older versions of Ubuntu:

- Download the `opensnitch` and `python3-opensnitch-ui` .deb files from [this releases page](https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch/releases):

  - If you're using a 64 bit system, download `opensnitch_1.5.2-1_amd64.deb` and `python3-opensnitch-ui_1.5.2-1_all.deb`
  - If you're using a 32 bit system, download `opensnitch_1.5.2-1_i386.deb` and `python3-opensnitch-ui_1.5.2-1_all.deb`
  - If you're using an ARM 64 bit system, or an ARM hard float system, download the corresponding .deb files
- Install both of these files by double clicking and installing them, or by running this on the command line:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i Downloads/opensnitch*.deb Downloads/python3-opensnitch-ui*.deb
  ```
- You can launch the OpenSnitch GUI tool by launching "OpenSnitch".

If for some reason you can't run OpenSnitch after installing it, you may be experiencing this bug ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch/issues/647), [Launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grpc/+bug/1971114)). To fix it, run on the command-line:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
pip3 install --ignore-installed --user grpcio==1.44.0
```

Pip installs modules to `~/.local/share/lib/python*`, so you can delete that directory if you want to undo the previous command.

Comment: Great tip and nice how-to.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might be good to you. [Firestarter](http://www.fs-security.com/) looks a powerful firewall program. Might be worth giving a shot.

But I would advise just using IPtables. As stated above it can be configured with ufw for ease of use.

Ubuntu has a great documentation for its [IPtables implementation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo). With this you dont really need an app. If you are comfortable with the cmd line then you wil be able to set up your firewall to drop everything leaving your PC. Without yourself adding a rule to allow it. eg. for example port 80 for webserver.

Once you have used IPtables you will wonder how you worked without it!

**EDIT:** Might find that its not so easy to get a sort of idiot proof firewall like that on Linux. And that's no way a dig at you I use it on my MacBook Pro ha! ( OSX is great imo ) Just the applications available on linux usually involve a bit more configuration.

Bill

Comment: -1: firestarter is just a network level firewall, it allows no control over per process rules.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://help.comodo.com/topic-83-1-158-1304-how-to-set-up-trustconnect-on-linux.html) is a guide on how to install comodo. I dont know if the program is as good as little snich. Hope that program is what you were looking for!

Answer (score 0):

InJoy firewall is by far the best option if you can afford it. ($60)

[InJoy](http://www.fx.dk/firewall/)

Hope this helps,

Leinardo

Answer (score 0):

SELinux:

A Linux kernel integrating SELinux enforces mandatory access-control policies that confine user programs and system servers to the minimum amount of privilege they require to do their jobs. This reduces or eliminates the ability of these programs and daemons to cause harm when compromised

SELinux has been integrated into version => 2.6

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux
http://www.nsa.gov/research/selinux/index.shtml
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-selinux/[image]

Comment: sure would be nice if App-Armor or SELinux could be tied in with UFW/GUFW to give some sort of application awareness to the in/out of packets through the firewall.

Comment: I remember way back that AppArmor had a gui, but they dropped it because it was not being maintained... which is a shame because it made dealing with AppArmor rules nice and easy.