# Get my app, having a kernel module, accepted by the review process of the Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: kernel, software-center, ppa

I have submitted an app divided in 3 parts:

- A kernel module
- A daemon
- A control panel

The first and last parts are free and open source, and packaged in a PPA.
The second one is closed source, and this is the part I want to sell trough the Ubuntu Software Center.

My app is -- as of now -- rejected due to the kernel module, and the fact that it is not on a safe place (PPA) as the reviewer told me.

When I have tried to publish the free and open source parts in the USC, I got the following message:

> Thank you for submitting a gratis Free Software application through
>   MyApps. At this time we are unable to process this request, as we are
>   working on the implementation of a new app upload process. To get your
>   software out to millions of Ubuntu users in the meantime, you can
>   either use a Personal Package Archive to distribute your app for free,
>   or you can define a price to charge for your app.

I am now looking for a solution (as he didn't gave me any directions).
How could I do to get my app accepted ? Anyone has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

FYI you can't use Launchpad (and a PPA) for closed source:

From https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+faq/585

*For Launchpad's purposes, a "project" is a body of work that is useable by itself. The project does not have to be software: it could be documentation, or any other kind of creative work. However, if it depends on proprietary (non-open-source) components to be useable in its normal mode of use or operation, then it would not qualify for free hosting. Proprietary projects are still welcome to use Launchpad, they just require a commercial subscription.*

Best regards.