# Is there a firewall that blocks a process and shows a dialog with buttons Allow, Drop, Disable?

Tags: firewall

Currently I use ufw and Firestarter, and I'm just learning how to use a firewall.

When I used windows there were a couple of firewalls that could block a process which tried to establish connection and show a dialog with the process name and buttons with preferred actions.

Is there deb package which can block connection and show which process tries to establish it, giving the user a choice what to do with the connection?

I really need it because I cannot figure out which process was blocked by Firestarter given that log entry:

```
Time            Port  Source        Destination    Protocol Service
Feb 13 21:55:09 12350 192.168.1.100 193.120.x.x    TCP       Unknown
```

Comment: Seems there is only one option

Comment: : *Leopard Flower* http://askubuntu.com/questions/45072/how-to-control-internet-access-for-each-program