# Desktop entry exec with sg

Tags: lubuntu, .desktop, lxqt

I'm using Lubuntu 20.04, (almost) freshly installed.
I've succesfully created few `.desktop` entries in `~/.local/share/applications/` for wine applications. However, there is one wine app which I would like to prevent from connecting to the internet. So I used an [approach](https://askubuntu.com/a/423105/1151448) with `no-internet group`. 
From `.desktop` entry, `wine "~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Folder/executable"` works well.
From terminal, `sg no-internet wine "~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Folder/executable"` works well. From terminal, `gtk-launch appname.desktop` containing the latter command in `Exec` works well. But from menu it does not launch: no errors, no messages, nothing. I also tried `sg no-internet -c 'wine "~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Folder/executable"'` and creating a `.sh` script, but the former does not even launch with `gtk-launch` with error `no application appname`, the latter also fails with `sh: 0: could not open appname-launcher.sh`.

How does one configure a `.desktop` file to launch something with `sg`? Why does `gtk-launch` launchs command and menu entry not?

The `appname.desktop` has permissions 777 (just in case).