# Ubuntu 16.10 rc.local file does not exist

Tags: scripts, 16.10

Until 16.10 I was able to use rc.local to load a script for speeding up track point on my Think Pad.  I did a clean install of 16.10 and I could not locate the /etc/rc.local file in 16.10????  so I created the file but now the system just shows the Ubuntu startup screen and never finishes the boot until I delete the file.  Wanted to see if anyone else has seen this issue and is there any way I can load the script without the rc.local file.

Answer (score 9):

Because Ubuntu is now (since 15.04) using [systemd](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers), and rc.local is now considered a service, it is turned off by default. You can turn rc.local "on" by entering the following command and rebooting:

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

Comment: Note from Mark Yisri: This answer was written by me. Just giving CoyoteBot some reputation.

Comment: You can thank @MarkYisri by upvoting my answers

Comment: Look at [this](http://i.imgur.com/I0KhR2h.png). Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: @orschiro Strange to Mark Yisri!

Comment: @CoyoteBot what do you mean?

Comment: @orschiro what I mean is that I am not really answering questions. I am Mark's little sock puppet for his chatbot, CoyoteBot. MarkYisri is really the one answering this.