# CPU frequency too high even with 'powersave' governor

Tags: 18.04, intel, cpu, cpufreq, governor

Recently I noticed my CPU sits most of the time at high frequencies, even with very little load.

It is an i5-7300HQ processor which should use frequencies between 800 MHz and 2.5 GHz (3.5 GHz with Turbo Boost).

Now even when load is about 2-8%, the frequencies I see are usually between 2.6 and 3.2 GHz, which means the CPU is almost always Turbo Boosting.

Before it was always 900 - 1200 MHz.

The scaling governor is set to powersave:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
powersave
powersave
powersave
powersave
```

In `/etc/default/grub` I have a line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_pstate=disable scsi_mod.scan=sync"
```

In `/etc/default/cpufrequtils`:

```
GOVERNOR="powersave"
```

There is no `/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/` dir

My system specs are:

- Laptop: HP Pavilion - 15-bc203nw
- OS:     Ubuntu (Xubuntu) 18.04.1 LTS
- CPU:    Intel Core i5-7300HQ

**EDIT**

After @WinEunuuchs2Unix suggestions I again have `/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/` dir.

Typing the following:

`cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq && paste <(ls *) <(cat *)`

gives the output:

```
affected_cpus                             0
cpuinfo_max_freq                          3500000
cpuinfo_min_freq                          800000
cpuinfo_transition_latency                0
energy_performance_available_preferences  default performance balance_performance balance_power power
energy_performance_preference             balance_performance
related_cpus                              0
scaling_available_governors               performance powersave
scaling_cur_freq                          3236541
scaling_driver                            intel_pstate
scaling_governor                          performance
scaling_max_freq                          3500000
scaling_min_freq                          3500000
scaling_setspeed                          <unsupported>
```

How can I set it to `powersave` (just changing it in `scaling_governor` file doesn't do anything).

Comment: If you are not using the intel_pstate CPU frequency driver, then it should be using the acpi-cpufreq driver by default. That driver using the powersave governor should always be a the minimum CPU frequency. So that is odd. Anyway, I agree with @WinEunuuchs2Unix 's answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer below. Frequencies have drastically dropped with kernel `4.14.98` a few days ago. Possibly it occurred sooner after `4.14.89` which was my last kernel installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer Version 3.0

Kernel version 4.14.98 has finally fixed problems I've noticed for last 6 months or so:

- When system is idle CPU frequency would spike to 3,000 MHz in Turbo Mode.
- When system is busy CPU frequency would simmer down to about 1,500 MHz.

Now as you can see when system is idle system is at 800 MHz as it should be:

[image]

## Answer Version 2.0

OP updated question with results of Initial Answer below and for whatever reason the governor is set to `performance` mode which runs all CPU's at max speed all the time.

We need to do the reverse of this answer: [Set CPU governor to performance in 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1021748/set-cpu-governor-to-performance-in-18-04/1084727#1084727):

Use: `sudo -H gedit /etc/rc.local` put insert this **before** the last line containing `exit 0`:

```bash
sleep 120 # Give CPU startup routines time to settle.
echo powersave | tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
echo 800000 | tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq
```

Save the file and reboot. Two minutes after rebooting your CPU's will settle down and run normally.

---

## What if `/etc/rc.local` doesn't exist?

From this: [Ubuntu 16.10 rc.local file does not exist](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840836/ubuntu-16-10-rc-local-file-does-not-exist)

you need to enter:

```bash
sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

---

## Initial Answer

According to: [`intel_pstate` CPU Performance Scaling Driver](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/admin-guide/pm/intel_pstate.html), `intel_pstate` status should be:

> **status**
>
> ```bash
> Operation mode of the driver: “active”, “passive” or “off”.
>
> “active”
>     The driver is functional and in the active mode.
> “passive”
>     The driver is functional and in the passive mode.
> “off”
>     The driver is not functional (it is not registered as a scaling driver with the CPUFreq core)
> ```

My first step would be to remove your kernel command line parameter `intel_pstate=disable`.

Reboot and type the following:

```bash
$ cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq

$ paste <(ls *) <(cat *)

affected_cpus                             0
cpuinfo_max_freq                          3500000
cpuinfo_min_freq                          800000
cpuinfo_transition_latency                0
energy_performance_available_preferences  default performance balance_performance balance_power power 
energy_performance_preference             balance_performance
related_cpus                              0
scaling_available_governors               performance powersave
scaling_cur_freq                          832522
scaling_driver                            intel_pstate
scaling_governor                          powersave
scaling_max_freq                          3500000
scaling_min_freq                          800000
scaling_setspeed                          <unsupported>
```

This is what I have in a default configuration without `intel_pstate=disable`.

**Pay close attention** to `scaling_max_freq` and `scaling_min_freq`.

You might want to temporarily uninstall CPU Freq Utils package:

```bash
sudo apt remove cpufrequtils
```

I have never found a need for it and it might be mucking your system up. Later you can install it again (if need be) with:

```bash
sudo apt install cpufrequtils
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87192/discussion-between-doug-smythies-and-wineunuuchs2unix).

Comment: @DougSmythies Kernel is finally fixed. See my answer 3.0 above.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Hmmm... that actually doesn't make sense to me. I would like to understand exactly what changed and why.

Comment: @DougSmythies I may have spoken too soon. This morning (after resuming from suspend) it reverted to old ways of +2,500 MHz and 2% CPU load when pausing youtube. I will do more testing and possibly revert Answer 3 version tonight.