# Ubuntu 19.04 Overheating on Idle

Tags: dell, cpu, 19.04, overheating

I recently installed ubuntu 19.04 on my laptop (Dell G7 7590). I have faced severe overheating issues. My laptop hits around 71 degrees centigrade even on idle. I've tried installing TLP, powertop, laptop-mode, slimbook and nothing seems to have helped so far. I believe the problem is in the CPU running at max freq at all times, but I don't know how to resolve this.

I tried:

```
echo '1' > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

and there has been no change.

I am fairly new to both Linux and the forum so any help will be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**

When I try to detect the sensors by running:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

It gets stuck at:

```
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM80'...
```

Also:

```
sensors| grep fan
```

Gives no output

How do I resolve this?

**UPDATE**

It appears that my CPU has minimal usage and the laptop still heats up

[image]

It clocks at 1.8 to 2.2 GHz, with max freq at 4.1 GHZ, yet I cant seem to find the source for it heating up.

**UPDATE**

I reinstalled Ubuntu 19.04 and the nvidia drivers, TLP, CPUfreq, which seems to have resolved the problem. Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix and @Doug Smythies for your help.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/391474/stop-cpu-from-overheating

Comment: Related 2: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102311/cpu-frequency-too-high-even-with-powersave-governor

Comment: Your processor would default to using HWP (Hardware P-State) control via the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver. As a test, try disabling HWP, via `/etc/default/grub`, with `intel_pstate=no_hwp` added to whatever is already on the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line. Remember to `sudo update-grub` after, and keep a copy of the original first. Also, `turbostat` (linux-tools-common package) is the best tool for this investigation. Start with `sudo turbostat --Summary --quiet --show Busy%,Bzy_MHz,PkgTmp,PkgWatt,GFXWatt,IRQ --interval 5` and modify as needed as you drill down into it.

Comment: My laptop used to have Windows, and the fans worked normally there, but they are too slow in Ubuntu. They spin at bare minimum speed. How do I rectify that? @WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: My fans work normally in Linux and Windows 10. I didn't do anything special other than installing `tlp` and `thermald` with default settings.